# Reverse Word Wise using basics of C++

Tags: c++, string

The **question** Goes like this ( my code in the last )

Reverse the given string word wise. That is, the last word in given string should come at 1st place, last second word at 2nd place and so on. Individual words should remain as it is.

**Input format :**
String in a single line

**Output format :**
Word wise reversed string in a single line

**Constraints :**
0 <= |S| <= 10^7
where |S| represents the length of string, S.

**Sample Input 1:**
Welcome to Coding Ninjas

**Sample Output 1:**
Ninjas Coding to Welcome

**Sample Input 2:**
Always indent your code

**Sample Output 2:**
code your indent Always

This code is in c++:

```
void reverseStringWordWise(char input[]) 
{
    // Length
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; input[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        count++;
    }
    int len=count;
    
    //reversing the complete string
    int i=0;
    int j=len-1;
    while(i<j)
    {
        char temp=input[i];
        input[i]=input[j];
        input[j]=temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    
    //individual reverse
    
    
    int k=0;
    int a,b;
    for(;k<len;)
    {
        for(;input[k]==' ';k++)
        {
            b=k-1;
            break;
        }
        
        while(a<b)
        {
            char temp=input[a];
            input[a]=input[b];
            input[b]=temp;
        }
    }      
}
```

can someone help me with the logic of reversing the individual word, c or c++ works.

Comment: Isn't this (Coding Ninjas) a coding challenge site? You are supposed to solve these questions yourself, but do you have a particular question about C?

Comment: `vector<string> v; string word; while(cin >> word) v.push_back(word); auto sep = ""; for(auto it = v.rbegin(); it != v.rend(); ++it) { cout << sep << *it; sep = " "; } cout << "\n";`

Comment: Your implementation has undefined behaviour: you never initialize `a` before reaching `while(a<b)` for the first time.

Comment: What problem are you having with the code you've posted?

Comment: First thing on the ageda should be: Which programming language are you using? It looks like C code.

Comment: If it's C, then the right tool for the job is `strtok`.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should be using `std::string` instead of character arrays.  Character arrays can overflow and don't expand as necessary.

Comment: yes this is a question from a learning site, but my doubt was not resolved there, that's why I'm here.

this code is in c++, but the explanation can be either in c/c++ as understand both theie syntax

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, prefer to use `std::swap`.  The C language doesn't have `std::swap`.

Comment: Since you tagged as C, be aware of `strtok`.  The `strtok` function modifies the character array.

Comment: Me I wonder where the myth that using pointers and arrays was "the basics" came from.

Comment: @DhruvKuchhal -- Those competitive coding websites are designed for *experienced* programmers to answer their random puzzle questions.  They are not to be used as learning tools in writing proper C++ programs.  Take a look at the answers posted to your question -- do any of them look like your attempt?  The only way to give answers looking like what you see here is through *experience* in using C++ properly, something you cannot gain from using those sites.

Answer (score 3):

I would get rid of the `char[]`s and use `std::string`.

Example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <list>

void reverseStringWordWise(std::string input) {
    std::list<std::string> words;

    for(auto sit = input.begin();;) {
        // find a space from `sit` and forward
        auto eit = std::find(sit, input.end(), ' ');

        // store the word first in the list
        words.emplace_front(sit, eit);

        if(eit == input.end()) break; // last word, break out
        sit = std::next(eit); // start next search after the found space
    }
    // print result
    for(auto& word : words) std::cout << word << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    reverseStringWordWise("Hello world");    
}
```

Output

```
world Hello
```

If you don't want the trailing space after the last word:

```cpp
void reverseStringWordWise(std::string inp) {
    std::list<std::string> words;
    for (auto sit = inp.begin(), eit = sit; eit != inp.end(); sit = eit + 1) {
        eit = std::find(sit, inp.end(), ' ');
        words.emplace_front(sit, eit);
    }

    if(auto it = words.begin(); it != words.end()) {
        std::cout << *it;
        for(++it; it != words.end(); ++it) std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote again just for "I would get rid of the char[]s and use std::string.".

Comment: @infinitezero :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard library algorithms to shorten the code. If you've got start and end iterators, you can use `std::reverse`, you can use `std::strlen` to calculate the end iterator and you can use `std::find` to identify the next word boundary. Assuming every word seperator is a space character, this could result in the following algorithm

```
void reverseStringWordWise(char input[])
{
    if (input[0] == '\0')
    {
        return;
    }

    auto const end = input + std::strlen(input);

    std::reverse(input, end);
    
    auto wordEnd = input;

    while(true)
    {
        auto wordStart = wordEnd;
        wordEnd = std::find(wordStart, end, ' ');
        std::reverse(wordStart, wordEnd);
        if (wordEnd == end)
        {
            break;
        }
        ++wordEnd;
    }
}

int main() {
    char input1[] = "Welcome to Coding Ninjas";
    char input2[] = "Always indent your code";

    reverseStringWordWise(input1);
    reverseStringWordWise(input2);
    std::cout << input1 << '\n'
        << input2 << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, using [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack):

```
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

void reverseStringWordWise(std::string input)
{
   std::stack<std::string> wordStack;
   std::istringstream strm(input);
   std::string word;
   // push each word on the stack
   while (strm >> word)
      wordStack.push(word);

   // pop stack for each word
   while (!wordStack.empty())
   {
      std::cout << wordStack.top() << ' ';
      wordStack.pop();
   }
}

int main()
{
   reverseStringWordWise("Welcome to Coding Ninjas");
}
```

Output:

```
Ninjas Coding to Welcome
```

Comment: _"Ninjas Coding to Welcome"_ was worth an upvote in itself :-)

Answer (score 0):

With boost, it's easier:

```
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp>

std::string reverse_words(std::string s)
{
    boost::char_delimiters_separator<char> const sep(" ");
    boost::tokenizer<boost::char_delimiters_separator<char>> const words(s, sep);
    return boost::algorithm::join(std::reverse(words.begin(), words.end()), " ");
}
```

In C++, you are expected to use algorithms and not bother with rewriting everything from scratch (unless you are writing a library such as boost). Especially, as others mentioned, reading/writing to arrays directly is most often going to end up with errors (your code is missing several boundary checks).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modern C++ version. The algorithm is to reverse each word and then reverse the whole string. The code takes the string by value so it has a copy of the string and then modifies the string in-place and returns it. It uses no extra memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::string word_reverse(std::string s) {
    auto it = s.begin();
    while(it != s.end()) {
        auto it2 = std::find(it, s.end(), ' ');
        std::reverse(it, it2);
        it = it2 + (it2 != s.end());
    }
    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    return s;
}
    
int main() {
    std::string s = "Always indent your code";
    std::string t = word_reverse(s);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex:-

````
//   ```c++
    #include <regex>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    
    using it = std::regex_iterator<std::string::const_reverse_iterator>;
    
    int main() {
        const std::string s = "Always indent your code.";
        std::regex regex("[\\w]+");
        
        for (auto i = it(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), regex); i != it(); ++i) {
            auto w = i->str();
            std::copy(std::rbegin(w), std::rend(w), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
            std::cout << ' ';
        }   
    }
````

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps, im just learning so

```
void reverseStringWordWise(char input[]) {
// Write your code here
int i=0,j=0;
while(input[i]!='\0')
{
    i++;
    j++;
}
int q=j;
j--;
i=0;
while(j>i)
{
    int t=input[i];
    input[i]=input[j];
    input[j]=t;
    i++;
    j--;
}
i=0,j=0;
int c=0,d=0;
while(i<q)
{
    if(input[i]==' '||i==q-1)
    {
        c=i-1;
        if(i==q-1)
        {
            c=i;
        }

    }
    while(c>=d && (input[i]==' '||i==(q-1)))
    {
        int t=input[c];
        input[c]=input[d];
        input[d]=t;
        c--;
        d++;
    }
    if(input[i]==' ')
    {
        d=i+1;
    }
    i++;
}

}
```

'''

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code; it will definitely work:

```
int length(char input[])
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;input[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
//length reverse
void reverseStringWordWise(char input[]) {
    int i=0;
     int   len=length(input);
    int j=len-1;
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    { char temp=input[i];
    input[i]=input[j];
    input[j]=temp;
    j--;

    }
    //word reverse
    int k=0;
     i=0;
   int count=0;
   while(count<=len)
   {
    for(;input[i]!='\0';i++)
    {   if(input[i]!=' ')
        count++;
        else break;
    }
    j=count-1;
    for (; k < j; k++) {
      char temp = input[k];
      input[k] = input[j];
      input[j] = temp;
      j--;
    }
    i++;
    k = i;
    count++;
   } 
   
}
```